# How can I search in a column of a datatable in SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

This is the code:

```
// get id groupe
cmd = new SqlCommand("select idgroupe from enseigner where idformateur = '"+Session["matricule"]+"'", cn);

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(dr);
dr.Close();

// get group name
cmd = new SqlCommand("select nom from groupe where ID IN("+dt.Columns[0]+")", cn);

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

// fill dropdown list 
while (dr.Read())
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
}

dr.Close();
cn.Close();
```

I can't get all columns, like this I get just the name of columns, so that make problem.

I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : 'Nom de colonne non valide : 'idgroupe'

NB: `idgroupe` is the name of column in DataTable

Comment: You get just the *nom of columns* because there are no rows returned for the IDs you've provided. There is nothing in an empty dataset other than the column name(s).

Comment: oh .....but when i count it i find 3 elements there and that true !!!

Comment: Then you'll need to [edit] your post to include the code where you're trying to use the results. We can't help you with code we cannot see.

Comment: i already put the code ...

Comment: Oh the horror! Regardless of anything you should Never EVER pass parameters like that. Use SqlParameters. The error seems to be on the first command, does the enseigner table/view have a column named idgroupe?

Comment: yap , the first command returns a table with one column named idgroupe. But can tell me plz why i should use SqlParamers ? thank you a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is the command

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("select nom from groupe where ID IN("+dt.Columns[0]+")", cn);
```

This text translates to "select nom from groupe where ID IN(idgroupe)"
Meaning that is searching the column nom on table group where Id is in column idgroupe, that probably does not exist.

We don't know what you actually want, but there should at least be simple quotes around the parentheses, similar to what you did on the first command.

Anyway, you should read about Sql Injection (https://www.troyhunt.com/stored-procedures-and-orms-wont-save/)

And change your commands to something like

```
using(cmd = new SqlCommand("select idgroupe from enseigner where idformateur = @id", cn))
{
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Session["matricule"]);
  (...)
}
```

Comment: I mean by that command :"select nom from group where id in(1,5,4,8,11)"  cause the first command return table with many elements type Int , So I want to get the names of groups with id in that list of int elements (.dt columns). I hope that clarify my problem , thank you

Comment: Refer to https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/passing-multiple-parameters-in-sql-in-clause-with-sqlcommand

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers